# icons break on deployment using rails, spree with fancy extension

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, icons, spree, dev-to-production

I have spree 2-1-stable running with rails 4.0.2.  I added the spree-fancy extension.
Everything looks good on the development server.

When I deploy to production the icons break (e.g. cart, search, account icons).  The icon html is:

```
<i class="icon-basket"></i>
```

the css is:

```
.icon-basket:before { content: '\e73d'; }
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: 'icons';
}
```

I can replicate the issue with my development environment by removing the line: `font-family: 'icons'`.  This issue happened on *Heroku* and on my own server running *nginx*.  Examining the source html and css on both pages, everything looks the same.  Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing Asset pre-compile in heroku?

Comment: @UriMikhli- yes, I had to pre-compile assets before pushing to heroku.  spree has to access the database during initialization (or something like that).

Comment: did you save your /assets to repo before pushing to heroku?

Comment: @UriMikhli yes I did.  logs show that the browser requests image files which the server cannot locate (e.g. "/logo3.png").  I am not able to locate such files in my development server logs.  Thanks.

Comment: Something similar is happening to us, Dev and Staging are correct, but when deployed to Prod (nginx Unicorn) the icons are all wrong. We are not using spree-fancy, but instead installed fontello. We believe that it's something to do with the fontello.svg file, but still not sure what is going on. When I figure this out I'll post an answer here. If you figure it out first please post the answer.

Comment: @UriMikhli I have been viewing my site with linux/firefox.  Yesterday I installed new fonts and the search icon started working and the others turned into Chinese characters.  The issue looks different on windows.  Browser doesn't seem to matter.  Hope that sheds some light.

Comment: @UriMikhli I found a quick fix.  My production server couldn't find /assets/icons.woff  so I downloaded it from my development server and pasted it into /assets/images/  I don't know where my development server got the file from.  I couldn't find it in my local app or in the spree gem repositories.  Hope this helps.  I would appreciate knowing more about the cause of the problem and a better solution if you come up with anything.  Merry Christmas.

Comment: I'll get back to you after I've had a chance to check if that solves my problem as well. I have a suspicion, but we'll see.  Happy Holiday

Comment: I never did solve the problem. Our UI dev pulled Fontello icons out and we're now using a different approach.Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Take a look to my answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue with rails 4.0.2 and spree 2-1-stable and it took me the last 4 hours to find a workaround. You already mentioned it yourself, but maybe it saves others some time (even if it's not a real solution):

Just find the missing .woff's or whatever and copy them to the right directory. In my case those were needed:

1. icon.wuff from [github.com/spree/spree_fancy](https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/tree/master/vendor/assets/fonts)
2. fontawesome-webfont.woff from [here](http://fontawesome.io/)
3. ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png from jquery (just google it)

Just insert them into the directory the server/browser is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. You need to precompile with production environment

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily change the database configuration file for production envroiment be set to use Sqlite3 gem in `config\database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Add `gem 'sqlite'` to your `Gemfile` if not present already and do a

```
$ bundle install && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

When files are generated, undo the changes in `Gemfile` and `config\database.yml` do a `$ bundle install` and deploy